# LightGallery multiple galleries on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gallery, lightgallery

Installed lightGallery today on my site and here is the part of code:

```
<div class="portfolio-content">      
            <ul id="portfolio_filters" class="portfolio-filters">
                    <li class="active">
                      <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link grph active" data-group="graphics">Banners</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="filter btn btn-sm btn-link" data-group="logo">Logo</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

   <div id="portfolio_grid" class="portfolio-grid portfolio-masonry masonry-grid-3">

                    <figure class="gallery-graphics" data-src="images/bnrs/01-bnr.png" data-sub-html="<h4>Banner 1</h4>" data-groups='["graphics"]'>
                      <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="images/bnrs/01-bnr.png"></a>
                    </figure>

                    <figure class="gallery-logo" data-src="images/logo/01-logo.png" data-sub-html="<h4>Logo 1</h4>" data-groups='["logo"]'>
                      <a href=""><img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo/01-logo.png"></a>
                    </figure>

   </div>
</div>
```

Single main container with id #portfolio_grid has 2 galleries with different selectors - 1 for banner images, 2 for logos. I want to see 2 different galleries on click showing 1/1 images each instead of 1/2, so I tried to understand lightGallery HTML markup instructions and wrote this code:

```
$('#portfolio_grid').lightGallery({
    hash: false,
    selector: '.gallery-graphics'
});

$('#portfolio_grid').lightGallery({
    hash: false,
    selector: '.gallery-logo'
});
```

which normally works for first gallery, but doesn't work for second. I tried to wrap `<figure>...</figure>` in divs with unique id, but in my case it breaks the site.

After this I tried another solution relating to lightGallery's own destroy() function and wrote this code which partially works only once - I have 1/1 image in first gallery and 1/1 image in second gallery. Second click on gallery image breaks the site.

```
var $lg = $('#portfolio_grid');

$lg.lightGallery({
  hash: false,
  selector: '.gallery-graphics'
});

$lg.on('onCloseAfter.lg', function(event) {
  $lg.data('lightGallery').destroy('true');

  $lg.lightGallery({
    hash: false,
    selector: '.gallery-logo'
  });
});
```

How to make lightgallery work with single id and many different selectors? Please help.

Comment: Why did you put the second lightGallery init IN the onCloseAfter.lg event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (cleaning up *both* lightGalleries)

```
var $lg = $('#portfolio_grid');

$lg.lightGallery({
    hash: false,
    selector: '.gallery-graphics'
});

$lg.on('onCloseAfter.lg',function(event){
 $lg.data('lightGallery').destroy('true');
});

$lg.lightGallery({
    hash: false,
    selector: '.gallery-logo'
});

$lg.on('onCloseAfter.lg',function(event){
 $lg.data('lightGallery').destroy('true');
});
```